# How to make a batch file answer a user prompt

Tags: batch-jobs

I have a batch file that runs a command, and one of those commands requires you to type in yes and hit enter.

Is there any way that the batch file can do this?

Comment: depends pretty strongly on whether that command reads stdin or opens the tty itself... can you "echo yes | that-command" and have it work?

Comment: That's what `yes |` is for, but your first course of action should be to look for an option you can pass to the script or to whatever command the script is invoking which will suppress the confirmation prompt. There normally exist such options because requiring interactive confirmation is antisocial toward automation.

Comment: @Celada it is a licence agreement, so I do not think there is any way.

Comment: Not for nothing, but.. I might hesitate to automatically accept a license agreement on behalf of the user.  (If that is, in fact, what your script tries to do.  Perhaps not.)

Comment: @NathanielDSouza: Maybe so, but not necessarily :-) FWIW the [Let's Encrypt client](https://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/man/letsencrypt.html) has an option `--agree-tos` that automatically accepts the terms of service, meant for use in automation.

Answer (score 1):

'**Expect**' should work see http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Expect

Note every time an Expect is used, the results are stored in a variable called $expect_out. This should allow your script to feed back to the user
Other benefits is that it allows conditional behavior of what to send next based on the circumstances.